# rt_raster_to_gdal: Could not load the output GDAL driver

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, postgis-raster

I have a postgresql remote database where all postgis and raster features have been enabled.

I am trying to execute a query of a raster table within a schema but the system returns the following error

```
rt_raster_to_gdal: Could not load the output GDAL driver
```

by using the following code

```
import psycopg2
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile
import rioxarray as riox
    
# DB Configuration
dbname = "Database"
dbuser = "user"
dbpass = "pass"
dbhost = "host.com"
dbport = "8080"

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect(database=dbname, user=dbuser, password=dbpass, host=dbhost, port=dbport)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    print("Database connected successfully")
except:
    print("Database not connected successfully")
curs.execute("select ST_AsGDALRaster(st_union(rast), 'GTIFF') from schema.table;")
result = curs.fetchone()
```

I have tried also to add the follow code to previouse script but nothing change

```
curs.execute("SET postgis.gdal_enabled_drivers = 'ENABLE_ALL';")
```

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For GTiff output, access to out-db raster bands must be enabled. You can read more about this configuration option here: https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_enable_outdb_rasters.html

Enable it for your current session with

```sql
SET postgis.enable_outdb_rasters = True;
```

Please note that for this option to have any effect you still need the necessary GDAL drivers to be enabled in the PostGIS environment. Namely, the driver for GTiff.